# Send package.json [version] to Angularjs Front end for display purposes

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, package.json

Is there a simple way to send the package.json file to the front end which is Angular js 1. I need to show the version the project is at. Using Gulp on a MEAN stack. Currently I have not found a way to do this.

#### Edit.

Not using Gulp on MEAN stack to get it I am just stating what is being used for the project to run. I though this might help.

Comment: What do you mean, when you say send? You want just show versions of your packages?

Comment: @Mikki , absolutely yes. I just need to be able to view my package.json's version for example in the client the view would be | version : 0.2.3 . But the package.json file is in node and the front end is all angular js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tried and this works for me.

Create a global variable in you app.js file,

```
global.__base = __dirname + '/';
```

Create a router like this,

```
app.get('/getVersion', function(req, res) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    var path = require('path');
    var obj;
    var pathToFile = path.resolve(__base, 'package.json');

    fs.readFile(pathToFile, 'utf8', function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        obj = JSON.parse(data);
        res.send(obj);
    });
});
```

You should be able to get your entire package.json in your response.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can either copy version from the package.json into needed HTML file during build process or create some endpoint which will return current version from package.json

Something like this: `GET /api/version`